# Accessing an API nested object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access from an API the values of some currencies, and I'm not managing to get them from within the function.

The API returns after parsing this: `{"ETH":{"USD":188.01},"BTC":{"USD":10330.41}}`

This is the code I used:

```
fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=ETH,BTC&tsyms=USD')
    .then(val => val.json()).then(data => {
        info = data; for (var item in data) { console.log(item.USD) }
    });
```

It logs undefined.

When I do in it `console.log(item)`, it logs `ETH` and `BTC` as strings and not as objects as they should be.
When I write in the console (outside of .then) `info.ETH.USD`, I get the results.

What did I get wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it was not working for you because you were looping through the object and returning the keys and not the actual object. `item` refers to `keys` of the object.

Try this:

```js
fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=ETH,BTC&tsyms=USD').
then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log("The object", data)
  for(var item in data) {
    console.log(data[item])
  }
})
```

**Now you can refer to the USD property as** `data[item].USD`.

Comment: Mark it as the correct answer if it helped you, will help future readers.

Comment: Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: In JavaScript, you have to train yourself to think "key" after saying "for".  Because `for` gives you _keys_, not _values_. It's `for (key in `   It's *not* `for (value in`.  This applies to both objects and arrays.  You may think I'm silly, but I remember it by saying _"Porky Pig"_.  "Porky" sounds like "for key".  Like "forky porky".  And the "Pig" is the big fat collection.  _"Porky in Pig"_ is _"for key in collection."_  My mind may work in weird ways, but maybe you'll remember this too.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused with JSON object manipulations.
While playing around with JSON Objects, Learn a few things which generally helps.

**Fetching value from JSON Object:**

```
var obj = {"ETH":{"USD":188.01},"BTC":{"USD":10330.41}};
```

**For fetching at the initial level:**

```
 obj["ETH"] // return {"USD":188.01}
```

**Fetching at nested level:**

```
 obj["ETH"]["USD"] // return 188.01
```

In your case, you are printing keys only

**Update your syntax:**

```
for(let item in data) {
    console.log(data[item]) 
 }
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "USD": 187.98
}
{
  "USD": 10302.56
}
```

Comment: The part that's still unclear to me is why console.log(data[item]) works, but console.log(data.item) returns undefined. Both ways should work on an object, as they do for the info var in the console itself e.g. info.ETH.USD.

Comment: When you try ```data.item```, the ```item``` should be present as a key in data which is not the case. Item is a variable which holds the key. Thus we need to use it like ```data[item]```